# Database requiring upgrade after 02/2016 CU implemented

Tags: 2013, cumulative-update, patching

I've implemented a Cumulative Update released in 02/2016 into our farm on 3/09/16. I ran the psconfig wizard at night on 3/10 to bring all the servers up to date.

Today I see the some errors/warnings in the "Configuration" section about databases requiring upgrades shown below:

[image]

The list above can be reached by going to Central Admin>Site Content>Review problems and solutions (FYI).

I've checked an article [here](http://www.justanothertechnologyguy.com/2011/11/databases-require-upgrade-or-not.html) that talks about upgrading Content DB but these are not Content DBs.

The above screenshot can be reached by navigating to CA and Upgrade and Migration> Review database status.

Does anyone have prior experience or knowledge on how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you run the psconfig using the command line or run through wizard?

Comment: Last night I ran psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait which worked and thinking everything will be fine. Today after finding the error, I tried psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures and still same error persists. I'm thinking restarting all servers after a few hours but won't be sure until then. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As you run the command line tool, I would go and run the Psconfig wizard through GUI( as this recommended).

- **PSCONFIGUI.EXE** is the UI based configuration wizard which performs several tasks one after the other after installing fixes.
- **PSCONFIG.EXE** is the command line tool which gives users granular control over all tasks that are executed and which is therefor often quicker than PSCONFIGUI.EXE.

[Why I prefer PSCONFIGUI.EXE over PSCONFIG.EXE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/08/20/why-i-prefer-psconfigui-exe-over-psconfig-exe/)

I would go with PsconfigUI 1st, if still not fixed then I would run Get-spprodcut -local, lastly i would try to reset the server.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I've never used that before so I would need some clarification. You're saying I should try PSConfigUI.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources? And should I run this only on the WFE or is this going to be ran on all servers? Please advise.

Comment: Not command line...go to start all program SharePoint > run the SharePoint Product configuration wizard on alls erver start from Central admin....with the option of dont disconnect this farm and this server will continue host CA...